# Depending field

Tags: nodes, entities, configuration

So i'm just begining to create a site in my company. the purpose of this internal website is to reference all setup we have in the company and i have to do it **on drupal 8**.

In order to do this i am creating a content type where i set all the field required. But i would like to have a specifique field for the screens of company users, because everyone can have 1,  or even 3 screen to work here.

That's why i try to create a field "screen" which contain other fields like "serial number", "constructor", "user name" etc... but i would like to have this for each screen.

> So if a user have 3 screen he should be able to have 3 fieds "screen"

but i do not find the way to do it ... someone can bring me a piece of solution please ?

Comment: Are you talking about monitors (computer screens)? You want the site to stretch over 1, 2 or 3 monitors? UPDATE, I understand you want to keep track of all screens in the company.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, the [Field collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) module offers the functionality you need:

> Provides a field-collection field, to which any number of fields can be attached.

However, on the [Field collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) page it is stated:

> [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) is likely to replace field collection for Drupal 8. Field
>   collection is on its way to being deprecated. It is recommended to use
>   paragraphs instead of field collection for Drupal 8 projects.

I would recommend to check out the [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) module, so that the content editor on your site is able to provide the different content (i.e., serial number, constructor, user name, etc.) per screen.